# Unknown lifecycle phase "\"

Tags: maven

I have executed this command

```
mvn org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-m2settings-maven-plugin:1.6.5:download \ 
    -DnexusUrl=https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com \
    -DtemplateId=magnolia-enterprise
```

in windows command propmt. And i am getting the following error.

```
Unknown lifecycle phase "\". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or 
a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or 
<plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle 
phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, 
process-resources , compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, 
process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, 
test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, 
pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, 
install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site,
site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the \ from the command line

In Windows, \ does not allow you to execute a multiline command as under linux.

In Windows the multiline separator is ^